# Does OculusGo support Background Services like Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusgo

I want to create a background service in OculusGo. I found a few links  [this](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/68737/are-android-background-services-possible-on-oculus-go), [this](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/65772/oculus-go-running-background-app-ignoring-the-scene-when-go-awakes-from-power-saving-mode) and [this](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/63531/oculus-go-background-services) but with no answers available.
 Is there any possibility to create a background service on OculusGo just like android background service.